# Shell Error while trying to perform a IF statement

Tags: shell

Good day.

I am trying to create a script to read each line of a specific file and then send each line to a second file depending on how many characters that line contains.

For example i have a file called numbers which contain the following information:

numbers.txt

```
5196803638
31995500317
5196396080
51999205240
5198158891
```

As you can see i have number with 8 or 9 numbers on each, i was trying to create a script that read a file line and send each number to its specific files.

```
!#/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

    echo $line

if [ "${#line}"= 8 ]; then
    $line> file8.txt
elif [ "${#line}"= 9 ]; then
    $line> file9.txt
else
    echo "Error"
fi

done < "$1"
```

But the only thing i get is the following

```
51996803638
My.sh: line 7: [: 11=: unary operator expected
My.sh: line 9: [: 11=: unary operator expected
Error
```

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would catch this error for you automatically.

Comment: BTW, it's very inefficient to redirect by filename inside a loop -- it means it's re-opening `file8.txt` every time it sees an 8-character line, re-opening `file9.txt` every time it sees a 9-character line, etc. You should be opening your output files outside the loop and reusing the file descriptors across multiple writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell's tokenizer is white-space sensitive. Use spaces around `=`, as in

```
if [ "${#line}" = 8 ]; then
    $line> file8.txt
elif [ "${#line}" = 9 ]; then
    $line> file9.txt
else
    echo "Error"
fi
```

Or, what about this, which I find more readable/maintainable/extendable:

```
case ${#line} in
  (8) $line > file8.txt;;
  (9) $line > file9.txt;;
  (*) echo Error;;
esac
```

Comment: It took the My.sh: line 9: [: 11=: unary operator expected part but I`m still only getting the "Error" part, i guess it is just not sending to the files or there something wrong with my if statements.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man What string do you enter? Are you aware that `${#line}` yields the number of characters in `$line`? Also, didn't you mean to write `echo $line >> file8.txt`? Note that your input file as shown does not contain any 8 or 9 character numbers.

Comment: I'd strongly consider `echo "$line" >&8` and `echo "$line" >&9` with `done 8>file8.txt 9>file9.txt` -- that way we aren't truncating our output files to a single line, which strikes me as unlikely to be correct. (And the sample lines given clearly are data, not commands, making an explicit `echo`, `printf '%s\n'`, etc. needed).

Comment: actually it was 10 or 11 characters. I just ran the script like with the amount of character changed but now im getting this error:
ContadorScript.sh: line 10: 51996803638: command not found

. i also give a file with all the numbers as a paremeter

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man, yes, that `command not found` is because you didn't follow the advice Jens gave you earlier, to use `echo`. (Presumably that advice was given in a comment not as part of the answer because you hadn't at that time said anything contradicting the idea that the behavior of the code you gave in your question -- of running the numbers as commands and writing those commands' output to file, rather than writing the numbers themselves -- could be intentional).

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers have 10 or 11 characters. When you compare numerical values, use `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-gt`, `-le`, `-ge`.

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line
    echo "Length = ${#line}"
    if [ ${#line} -eq 10 ]; then
        echo $line >> file10.txt
    elif [ ${#line} -eq 11 ]; then
        echo $line >> file11.txt
    else
        echo "Error"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Comment: It's very inefficient to use `>> file10.txt` inside a loop this way. If you ran `10>file10.txt` *outside* the loop, then put `>&10` *inside* the loop, we'd only be opening the file for write once, rather than re-opening it every time we want to write a single line, and closing it again after writing that one line.

Comment: BTW, you're missing a bunch of quotes -- right now if we had `line='*'` we'd be echoing a list of files in the current directory, for instance.